# Two-way SSL between two applications on the same Tomcat Server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ssl, https

I have the following scenario: two Java applications are running on the same Tomcat server -- let's call them App A and App B -- and they need to talk to each other via a webservice that is already up and running on App A. This webservice only accepts authenticated clients (clientAuth="true").

After all is configured, my Tomcat, acting as a client, sends an empty certificate chain to the server (which is the same Tomcat). Here's what I have done.

I generated a self-signed certificate for the server using keytool:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.jks -alias server
```

Then exported this certificate:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore keystore.jsk -alias server -file server.crt
```

And added it to the truststore:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore truststore.jsk -alias server -file server.crt
```

The SSL negotiation is as follows:

1. Client says hello
2. Server says hello and presents its certificate (generated above) for
   the client
3. Client accepts it (since it's in the truststore)
4. Server requires client certificate by presenting a list of valid DNs (which contains a single entry, the certificate generated above)
5. Client somehow decides it has no valid certificates and sends an empty cert chain
6. SSL handshake fails

I didn't post the actual SSL log because the client and the server are the same Tomcat, so everything is a mixed up mess.

What have I done wrong here? Keep in mind that these two apps are on the same server and the cert is self-signed. I also did a test where I generated another self-signed cert, exported it to a .p12 file and installed it in my browser, then called the webservice via URL directly into the address box, it worked flawlessly.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem are not the key(s) but how you initialize the HTTPS connection/web-service client used by App B.

Comment: @Robert I used the stubs generated by the wsimport command using the WSDL url (which starts with "https" and uses port 8443, properly configured). In my code, I use this: `MyWebService service = new MyWebService(url); IMyWebService client = service.getMyWebServicePort(); client.myMethod(...);` This class MyWebService extends javax.xml.ws.Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record to anyone that gets here...

I was able to do it in two ways. One was to prepare a special configuration file for my client application, named cxf.xml, as explained [in this link](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-ConfiguringSSLSupport). The other one was to use code to force the loading of the configuration, as follows:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "MyWebServicePort")
public IMyWebService getMyWebServicePort() {
    IMyWebService port = super.getPort(new QName("http://my.namespace/", "MyWebServicePort"), IMyWebService.class);
    try {
        // loads keymanager
        File keyStoreFile = new File(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
        String keyStorePass = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile), keyStorePass.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePass.toCharArray());

        KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();


        // loads trustmanager
        File trustStoreFile = new File(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
        String trustStorePass = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword");

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile), trustStorePass.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustFactory.init(trustStore);

        TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

        // configuring the connection
        Client cxfClient = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) cxfClient.getConduit();

        TLSClientParameters tlsParams = httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters();
        if (tlsParams == null) {
            tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
        }
        tlsParams.setKeyManagers(km);
        tlsParams.setTrustManagers(tm);

        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }

    return port;
}
```

I really don't know why it did not load the default config (with the JVM params). It is a mistery: debugging, I found out that when building the SSL connection, it actually uses a `DummyX509KeyManager`, meaning the configuration was not loaded. Could be a bug? I don't know.